# SPARQL query which binds URI of langague instead of variable

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have 2 graphs. One graph contains a bunch of triples with all universities and languages from wikidata and schema.org like this:

```
wd:Q5520695 a schema:CollegeOrUniversity ;
rdfs:label "Gandhi Institute of Engineering and Technology University"@en .
wd:Q5520696 a schema:CollegeOrUniversity ;
rdfs:label "Gandhi Institute of Technology and Management"@en .
wd:Q5520863 a schema:CollegeOrUniversity ;
rdfs:label "Ganesha University of Education"@en .

:Czech a schema:Language ;
    :bcpTag "cs"^^xsd:string ;
    rdfs:label "Czech"@en
            .

:Welsh a schema:Language ;
    :bcpTag "cy"^^xsd:string ;
    rdfs:label "Welsh"@en
            .

:Danish a schema:Language ;
    :bcpTag "da"^^xsd:string ;
    rdfs:label "Danish"@en
            .

:German a schema:Language ;
    :bcpTag "de"^^xsd:string ;
    rdfs:label "German"@en
            .
```

A second graph contains (among many other triples about a this person):

```
    _:node68 a schema:Person;
  schema:alumniOf _:node70, _:node72, _:node74;
  schema:knowsLanguage _:node78, _:node79, _:node80;
  schema:memberOf _:node81 .


_:node74 a schema:EducationalOrganization;
  schema:name "Gandhi Institute of Technology and Management";
  .


_:node78 a schema:Language;
  schema:name "German" .

_:node79 a schema:Language;
  schema:name "English" .

_:node80 a schema:Language;
  schema:name "Dutch" .

_:node83 a schema:Person;
  schema:name "Full Name" .
```

I would like to write a SPARQL Construct query which basically outputs the second graph, but using the URI's from the 1st graph which match the literals found in the second graph.

I managed to get the Select query to work, granted, it's probably not optimal, but it works. It returns 3 columns, which I basically just need serialized as triples. However, if I turn the select into a "construct" in order to make a graph which I can download in a given serialization, it no longer returns any results.

```
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT  ?id ?p ?newG

where { {
    VALUES (?p) {
        (schema:alumniOf)(schema:description) (schema:name) (schema:url) (schema:knowsLanguage) (schema:worksFor) (schema:jobTitle)}
    ?s a schema:Person .
    ?s ?p ?o .
    optional{
    ?o schema:name ?k
    }
    optional {?o ?a ?l}.
    bind(COALESCE (?k, ?l, ?o) AS ?g).
    optional {?s schema:name ?name}.
    bind(coalesce (?name, ?s) as ?id).

    #find the label, look it up in the object of rdfs:label of enumeration values, and bind the id instead of the original label.
#For Languages:
 optional{?id2 rdfs:label ?language.
            filter(contains(?language,?g)||contains(?g,?language)) .
            ?id2 rdf:type schema:Language .}
           
 #For University:
    optional {?id3 rdfs:label ?university.
            filter(contains(?university,?g)) .
            ?id3 rdf:type schema:CollegeOrUniversity .
            }
       bind(coalesce(?id2,?id3,?g) as ?newG)}  
    
    }
```

What am I missing?

Edit, the construct query which gets closest, after having noticed @UninformedUser's valid feedback that you cannot bind a string as a URI...

Now it's a matter of tweaking so that the subject's are not all blank nodes, but the actual subjects id's:

edit 2: Fixed the blank node issue also. Final query below:

```
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
CONSTRUCT {?id ?p ?newG}
WHERE {
  { SELECT distinct ?id ?p ?newG

where { 

    VALUES (?p) {
        (schema:alumniOf)(schema:description) (schema:name) (schema:url) (schema:knowsLanguage) (schema:worksFor) (schema:jobTitle)}
    ?s a schema:Person .
    ?s ?p ?o .
    optional{
    ?o schema:name ?k
    }
    optional {?o ?a ?l}.
    bind(COALESCE (?k, ?l, ?o) AS ?g).
    optional {?s schema:name ?name}.
            bind(URI(CONCAT("http://myprefix.ch/id/",
ENCODE_FOR_URI(?name))) as ?id).

    #find the label, look it up in the object of rdfs:label of enumeration values, and bind the id instead of the original label.
#For Languages:
 optional{?id2 rdfs:label ?language.
            filter(contains(?language,?g)||contains(?g,?language)) .
            ?id2 rdf:type schema:Language .}
           
 #For University:
    optional {?id3 rdfs:label ?university.
            filter(contains(?university,?g)) .
            ?id3 rdf:type schema:CollegeOrUniversity .
            }
       bind(coalesce(?id2,?id3,?g) as ?newG)}  
              
    }
        
        }
```

Comment: Can you include the `CONSTRUCT` part you tried?

Comment: what is the purpose of `optional {?o ?a ?l}.
    bind(COALESCE (?k, ?l, ?o) AS ?g).` ? Or better said, what is this query supposed to do at all?

Comment: wild guess, `bind(coalesce (?name, ?s) as ?id).` binds `?ìd` to a literal and not a URI? Given that a literal can't be the subject of an RDF triple, the CONSTRUCT query would return an empty result

Comment: so it turns out UninformedUser was right, you cannot bind a literal to a ?s of course. I fixed this like this:

bind(URI(CONCAT("http://myprefix.ch/id/",
ENCODE_FOR_URI(?name))) as ?id).

Now it works, and combined with a nice DISTINCT in my select statement, I get exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
CONSTRUCT {?id ?p ?newG}
WHERE {
  { SELECT distinct ?id ?p ?newG

where { 

    VALUES (?p) {
        (schema:alumniOf)(schema:description) (schema:name) (schema:url) (schema:knowsLanguage) (schema:worksFor) (schema:jobTitle)}
    ?s a schema:Person .
    ?s ?p ?o .
    optional{
    ?o schema:name ?k
    }
    optional {?o ?a ?l}.
    bind(COALESCE (?k, ?l, ?o) AS ?g).
    optional {?s schema:name ?name}.
            bind(URI(CONCAT("http://myprefix.ch/id/",
ENCODE_FOR_URI(?name))) as ?id).

    #find the label, look it up in the object of rdfs:label of enumeration values, and bind the id instead of the original label.
#For Languages:
 optional{?id2 rdfs:label ?language.
            filter(contains(?language,?g)||contains(?g,?language)) .
            ?id2 rdf:type schema:Language .}
           
 #For University:
    optional {?id3 rdfs:label ?university.
            filter(contains(?university,?g)) .
            ?id3 rdf:type schema:CollegeOrUniversity .
            }
       bind(coalesce(?id2,?id3,?g) as ?newG)}  
              
    }
        
        }
```